# Cassette lock ring compatibility

Tags: cassette, compatibility

Currently I’m using a 36-11t H092 microshift cassette. If I were to purchase shimano hg400, will my fr5.2 tool be able to use it on this lockring?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Yes, because the cassette lockring tool fitting is currently universal. The 5.2 will be able to do it.

Edit: not campy apparently. See comment for details.

Comment: Well, the 5.2 works with SRAM XD and many 3rd party cassettes, but I am pretty sure it won’t work with Campagnolo. So, not 100% universal, but Campy is definitively the minority.

Comment: @WeiwenNg One can safely assume that campy is compatible with nothing it seems.

Comment: Thank you for your guys help, i will get it today! A happy cassette makes a happy man

Comment: Do yourself a favor and acquire a new chain to go with the new cassette.  Running an unstretched chain on a drivetrain helps ensure longevity of the system.